# Changing Row Height in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on shortening the height of a bootstrap row (`class="table-form"`). I've tried a few things and have only been successful in changing the width of the row, and not the height. So far I have tried:

```
.table-form {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70%;
}

.table-form {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

As well as setting

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

For some reason I am only succeeding in changing the width. How can I successfully shorten the height of the entire row and its' contents while still keeping all the content centered?

Here is a link to the JS Fiddle (it might not show up inline but all the content should be on the same line/row): http://jsfiddle.net/j7z3845t/

I would appreciate any advice on how to adjust the row/content height.

Answer (score 0):

To use a percentage based height, all parent elements must have a height defined. In the following CSS I added a height of 100% to the #container div. I also made the background color of the row you want to change the height of to red for testing purposes. This way you can see the effects of your CSS easily.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
#container {
    height: 100%;
}
 body {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif !important;
    color: #CCFF66 !important;
    background: url(blackboard.jpg) no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    font-size: 1.5em !important;
}

.table-form {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70%;
    display: inline-block;
    background: red;
}

#header {
    padding: 30px !important;
}

#header h1 {
    font-family: 'Vast Shadow', cursive !important;
}

#first, 
#last, 
#phone,
#quant { /* Change error color message to red*/
    color: red;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive !important;
    font-size: 3em !important;
}

/* DISCOUNT TABLE */
#discount-table { 

}

th {
    font-size: 1.4em;
}

.table th, td { /* Table Style */
    text-align: center;
    padding: 25px 15px !important;
}

/* DIVIDER IMAGE */
#divider { 
    text-align: center !important;
}

#divider img {
    padding-top: 20px;
}

/* ORDER FORM */
#order-form {

}

.center { /* Center and condense form */
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 50%;
    width: 70%;
}

label {
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}

.form-group {
    margin-bottom: 2px !important;
}

#submit-button {
    text-align: center;
}

.btn {
    background-color: #C2C2FF !important;
}

.btn-default:active {
  background-color: #A3A3FF !important;
}

/* CUSTOM PRICE RESULT ON SUBMIT */

#result {
    color: #C2C2FF !important;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive !important;
    font-size: 3em !important;
    letter-spacing: 6px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The height on the `div class="table-form"` can't be controlled by putting a height directly on that element. The padding within each td is what is determining the overall height. Shrink down the padding and you'll get a smaller looking table.

If you want to keep the table row height as it is you could put an `overflow:scroll;` style on `div class="table-form"`.